# Avoiding duplicate rows among three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I am writing a query of 3 tables which has some calculations. A table by the name of customers may have one or multiple debits in table debit_items and each debit can have one or multiple credits in table credit_items. Here I should find total debit and total credit for each customer but the problem is that if a debit has more than one credit, that debit will be calculated as duplicate.

customers[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpi2I.png) debit_items[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IszVw.png) credit_items[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yK09.png)

The query I wrote is like this:

```
SELECT customers.*,
       sum(CASE
             WHEN debit_items.customer_id = customers.id THEN
              debit_items.debit_amount
             ELSE
              0
           END) as total_debit,
       sum(CASE
             WHEN credit_items.debit_id = debit_items.id THEN
              credit_items.credit_amount
             ELSE
              0
           END) as total_credit
  FROM customers
  LEFT JOIN debit_items
    ON customers.id = debit_items.customer_id
   AND debit_items.deleted = '0'
  LEFT JOIN credit_items
    ON debit_items.id = credit_items.debit_id
   AND credit_items.deleted = '0'
 GROUP BY customers.id
```

I would be thankful if anyone helps me.

Comment: ' each debit can have one or multiple credits '- really, you never have zero credits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group` first your `credit items` with its `sum()` based on `debit_id`, before joining to `debit` table.

```
SELECT customers.*,
       sum(CASE
             WHEN debit_items.customer_id = customers.id THEN
              debit_items.debit_amount
             ELSE
              0
           END) as total_debit,
       sum(CASE
             WHEN credit_items.debit_id = debit_items.id THEN
              credit_items.credit_amount
             ELSE
              0
           END) as total_credit
  FROM customers
  LEFT JOIN debit_items
    ON customers.id = debit_items.customer_id
   AND debit_items.deleted = '0'   
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT SUM(credit_amount) as credit_amount, debit_id from credit_items GROUP BY debit_id) as credit_items
        ON debit_items.id = credit_items.debit_id
   AND credit_items.deleted = '0'
 GROUP BY customers.id
```

Comment: thank you so much. you are really the best. it now works corrctly.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `LEFT JOIN`s to `INNER`s to return only the exact matches :

```
SELECT c.*,
       sum(CASE
             WHEN di.customer_id = c.id THEN
              d.debit_amount
             ELSE
              0
           END) as total_debit,
       sum(CASE
             WHEN ci.debit_id = di.id THEN
              ci.credit_amount
             ELSE
              0
           END) as total_credit
  FROM customers c
  JOIN debit_items di
    ON c.id = di.customer_id
   AND di.deleted = '0'
  JOIN credit_items ci
    ON di.id = ci.debit_id
   AND ci.deleted = '0'
 GROUP BY c.id
```